# Flask not receiving arguments from curl post

Tags: python, curl, flask

Trying to implement a flask API with the following code:

```
import tweepy,flask,os,flask_api,re,json,logging    
app = flask.Flask(__name__,template_folder='')
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def answer():
    app.logger.info('server responding')
    for key,value in flask.request.args.items():
        app.logger.info(key+':'+value)
    return 'Server on line'

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)#use_reloader=False
    logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
    app.logger.info('Successfull info message')
    app.logger.error('Successfull error message')
```

When I try to curl it wit windows,

```
curl -X POST -d query=cheese http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

(long form)

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --request POST  --data '{"query":"cheese"}'   http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

I get

```
 INFO in logtest: server responding
```

But not a single key/value pair is returned

Answer (score 4):

`flask.request.args` are [URL query parameters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.args).

`curl --data` is [body](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d).

You're sending a request body but expecting them to show up in the URL params. Which will obviously not work.

You need to access [request.data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.data) instead. There is a convenience method [get_json()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json) that you can use to have Flask parse the body into a dictionary for you.

Comment: get_json fails, it seems the curl is not sending in json format?

Comment: also, request.data is empty. Could you perhaps write the exact lines ?

Comment: Likely. You can check at the flask side by using is_json(): http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.is_json

Comment: In most cases, `request.data` is empty since it's used as a fallback. The attribute you want to access should be `get_json()` since you're passing `application/json` as the mimetype.